# "looks like" for non physical attribute

Tags: vocabulary

Can I use "looks like" for non-physical attributes?

For example:

> My father looks like my mother. They are both very kind.

Comment: In some contexts it is fine to use "looks like" to mean "seems like", for example "It looks like I'll be working late tonight".

Comment: @nnnnnn That was my first thought too when I read the question, but I can't seem to think up examples other than with he abstract "It".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your statement i understand that:

> My father looks like my mother

They are physically similar in appearance, shape etc

> They are both very kind

They both have the same attribute of being kind

If you want to describe the mother and father being similar in a non-physical way, you would say:
"My father is like my mother" (Implies they have similar ideas/beliefs)
In order to specify that they are both kind, you would say: "My father is like my mother, they are both kind"

Answer (score 0):

Comparison in people's appearance is made with the verb *look* (but there are other structures as well).

> He looks like his father. He is tall and slim.(We speak about similarly).

*Kind* describes character. We use *be* to compare people's character.

> He is like his father.He is very kind.